# TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined Ive check and checked

Tags: javascript, postman, mean

the name property is undefined.  I know this should be an easy fix.  So I should define it somewhere right?  But I have checked and checked and I cannot find the issue.  Could someone look at my code and see what my issue is?  At this point Im just building out the database.  I have a lot of comments in there because this is a review app before I start something new.  I am using Postman to test to see if the register route is working. So far it is giving me the error that it cannot read the property name of undefined.  Here is the whole error

On postman, I am using the POST method to http://localhost:3000/users/register
There is no Authorization
and in the headers, the key is Content-Type, and the value is application/json
So I'm pretty sure I am using Postman correctly.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at router.post (/Users/jonathanschroeder/Desktop/authapp/routes/users.js:12:24)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/jonathanschroeder/Desktop/authapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/jonathanschroeder/Desktop/authapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/Users/jonathanschroeder/Desktop/authapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/jonathanschroeder/Desktop/authapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /Users/jonathanschroeder/Desktop/authapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/Users/jonathanschroeder/Desktop/authapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/jonathanschroeder/Desktop/authapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (/Users/jonathanschroeder/Desktop/authapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
    at router (/Users/jonathanschroeder/Desktop/authapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/jonathanschroeder/Desktop/authapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/jonathanschroeder/Desktop/authapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /Users/jonathanschroeder/Desktop/authapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/Users/jonathanschroeder/Desktop/authapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/jonathanschroeder/Desktop/authapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at serveStatic (/Users/jonathanschroeder/Desktop/authapp/node_modules/serve-static/index.js:75:16)
```

models/user.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
//bcrpypt for encrpyption
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
//to connect to database 
const config = require('../config/database');


//Create the Schema
const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        require: true,
        unique: true //no two users can share the same email address. 
    },
    username: {
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        require: true
    }
});
//Create variable that can be used outside.  set that to mongoose model and pass in the UserSchema 
const User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

//Create two functions.  Get the user by ID and get the user by username.  Of course I need to do module.exports to use it outside. 
module.exports.getUserById = function(id, callback){
    User.findById(id, callback);
}

module.exports.getUserByUsername = function(username, callback){
    const query = {username:username} //findOne function takes in query
    User.findOne(query, callback);
}
//pass in 10 which means Number of rounds to use.  (Default is 10 anyways but I will pass 10)
//reference in case I forget www.npmjs.com/package/bcryptjs
//so it is confusing but this returns the hashed password.  
//https://busy.org/@nafestw/mean-tutorial-part-2-adding-a-user-model was a great tutorial for this.  
module.exports.addUser = function(newUser, callback){ //I did the callback in the route user.js where it gives success or fail and res.sends success or fail.
  bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
    bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
      if(err) throw err;
      newUser.password = hash;
      newUser.save(callback);
    });
  });
}
```

---

routes/users.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const passport = require('passport');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
//Now that I created the model I will bring it in here.
const User = require('../models/user');

//Registration 
router.post('/register', (req,res,next) =>{
    //res.send('registration');
    let newUser = new User({
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        username: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password  //I will run this password through bcrypt.hash which will has before db.
    });
    User.addUser(newUser, (err, user) =>{ //I will create this addUser function inside the models user.js
        if(err){
            res.json({success:false, msg:'Registration Failed!'})
        }else{
            res.json({success:true, msg:'User is Registered!'})
        }
    });
});




module.exports = router;
```

Here is the app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const passport = require('passport');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const config = require('./config/database')


mongoose.connect(config.database);


mongoose.connection.on('connected',function(){console.log('yay i am connected to database'+config.database)});


mongoose.connection.on('error',function(error){console.log('You have an error'+error)});



const app = express();


const users = require('./routes/users');



const port = 3000;


app.use(cors());


app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))


app.get('/', function(req,res){res.send('Sending Response')})


app.use('/users', users)


app.listen(port, function(){console.log('Server started on port '+port)})


app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

This is what I put in for postman

```
{
    "name":"John Doe",
    "email":"john@doe.com",
    "username":"johndoe",
    "password":"123456"
}
```

I think that is pretty much all the detail I can give.  But if you need more information please let me know.  The only other file that I have created is the database file 
config/database.js

```
module.exports = {
    database:'mongodb://localhost:27017/authapp', 
    secret:'NintamaRantaro'
}
```

I hope you can find my issue.  I am going to keep on looking as well

Comment: I don't know if this is an issue, but try to put `app.use(bodyParser.json());` before the route definition. Because your code looks good.

Comment: Hey Striped, you are correct!  I moved that line above the route definition and now I don't have that error.  But now on Postman I am getting {
    "success": false,
    "msg": "Registration Failed!"
}  Do you know why it's not success true?  Thank you for your help!

Comment: Just console log `err` to know about the error.

Comment: awesome, it was cause I had used the email before and so it was a duplication error, maybe i need to take off unique:true off my schema while testing.  Thank you Striped!  Huge help

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to read the body of a post request you need body-parser. See here:
[body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser)

and in the user route add

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

// create application/json parser
app.use(bodyParser.json())

// create application/x-www-form-urlencoded parser
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
```

depending on how you post your data

Comment: Thanks Giannis, I did have these but as Striped mentioned above I needed to put app.use line above the route definition.  Thanks for the quick response Giannis and Striped!  I love StackOverFlow!